# No. of variables in a switch statement - Java

Tags: java, switch-statement, enumeration, enumerated-types

Can you include more than one variable in a `switch` statement in Java?

```
enum Facing { North, South, East, West }

enum Forward { Right, Left }

Forward forward;

Facing facing;

Integer myNumber;
```

So it looks like this? And if so how would I go about implementing

```
switch (facing, forward) {
  case North, Right : facing 1 = East
}
```

I know this is wrong but wondered whether such a technique might work and how would I implement it?

Comment: The swicth statement can switch only primitve types and enums.So why won't you transform all your enums into a single number and than switch it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
switch(facing)
{
    case North:
         switch(forward)
         {
              case Right: // blah blah
              break;
         }
    break;
}
```

Comment: This is the way to do it. You can even remove some of the new-lines to put the code all on one line to make it more readable and concise. If using this solution though, don't forget to put `break`'s in all the right places because this could get out of hand quickly with all the permutations.

Comment: Yes this works, but surely an if statement would look nicer and simpler here?  `if (facing == North && forward == Right) {...} else if (...)`

Answer (score 9):

[Eng.Fouad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473237/no-of-variables-in-a-switch-statement-java/6473270#6473270) gives one way around that.

Another altenative might be to create a more complex Facing enum like this:

```
enum Facing {
  North {
    Facing right() { return East; }
    Facing left() { return West; }
  },
  East {
    Facing right() { return South; }
    Facing left() { return North; }
  },
  South {
    Facing right() { return West; }
    Facing left() { return East; }
  },
  West {
    Facing right() { return North; }
    Facing left() { return South; }
  };
  abstract Facing right();
  abstract Facing left();
}
```

Such a construct also allows for easy chaining so that you could write a generic reverse routine like this:

```
Facing reverse(Facing facing) { return facing.right().right(); }
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems like it belongs in Facing:

```
enum Facing {

    North, East, South, West;

    public Facing turn(Forward f) {
        return values()[(ordinal() + (f == Forward.Right ? 1 : 3)) % 4];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting with [JDK 7](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/features/), you could simulate this with a Switch on a String:

```
Facing facing = Facing.North;
Forward forward = Forward.Right;

String facingForward = facing + "-" + forward;
switch(facingForward){
    case "North-Right": return East;
    ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Effectively you are modelling a set of state transitions, when you're in a particular state (eg. Facing North) certain actions (eg. turn 90 clocwise) result in a new State ( facing East)

You can model such things with a host of nested switch statements or some such. I think you may do best to actually model the states as explicit classes, perhaps derived from an abstract base class which defines the actions.

I suspect that if your states or actions become marginally more complex you'll find you need the classes.